# Common Validation for Client and Server

Tags: javascript, java, spring, validation

I have a java backend program written in Spring and my front end is JSP, CSS, Javascript.

I want to create a validation that is shared by both Server and Client so that I only have one (1) area of change.

My initial plan is to create an XML validation configuration that client will load and read upon compilation of JSP and of course with the help of javascript and jquery to trigger the validation.

As for the Server side, java will also load the XML configuration from backend and parse the values submitted by the JSP.

Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: Any ideas for what ? Your approach seems doable...

Comment: I mean is there any better approach than my initial plan?

Comment: Your XML approach seems doable. I've only tended to see HTML5 and Javascript validation on front end (client) and null checks/brief validation checks on backend. If I was to go down your path, I would lean more on JSON than XML. But that's a personal preference.

Comment: You could check out json schema, this can hold pretty much any validation pattern but might be a little complex. Also I found that libraries or documentation for it is not that extensive.

Comment: I'll check the json validator, can this also validate POJOS and other request from client side?